# регистрация JSP как Servlet. Сервер Tomcat

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlet, web.xml

Делаю приложение на jsp. хочу чтобы страница загружалась по определенному адресу - для этого делаю как советуется в документации Oracle:

> Registering a JSP as a Servlet

в web.xml создал код

```html
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>myFoo</servlet-name>
  <jsp-file>myJSPfile.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>myFoo</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/main</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

файл myJSPfile.jsp лежит в папке webapp. При деплои сервера получаю ошибку:

```
[2017-01-03 10:21:56,182] Artifact GuestApp:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
03-Jan-2017 22:21:56.464 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1]     rg.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)...

03-Jan-2017 22:21:56.474 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception invoking method manageApp
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)...

03-Jan-2017 22:21:56.474 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1]       org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception invoking method createStandardContext 
javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Exception invoking method manageApp
at ...
```

Почитав форум, я понял, что это может быть из того, что в mappinge у меня указан отсуствующий сервлет, но запись то по документации оракл. что делать?

Comment: По какой документации вы это делаете?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman По вот этой: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/webapp/configurejsp.html

Comment: А вас не смутило, что это для WebLogic?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman Вы абсолютно правы! Мне даже немного стыдно)

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Не надо наводить тень на плетень. Это совершенно стандартный маппинг. Было бы что-то специфическое для weblogic, то было бы записано в каком-нибудь weblogic-web.xml, а не в стандартном же web.xml, который один и тот же для всех и работать должен одинаково у всех.

Comment: @Sergey я ничего не сказал про мапинг, про конфигурацию и пр, Я сказал, что руководство написано для одного сервера и вполне может не подходить  к другому. Потому, что его могли не проверять совсем. Я видел как пишется документация в больших корпорациях.

Answer (score 1):

Для Tomcat для меппинга JSP страницы требует следующую запись:

```html
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>myFoo</servlet-name>
  <jsp-file>/myJSPfile.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>myFoo</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/main</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Обратите внимание, что перед названием JSP файла стоит "/":

**/**(!!!)myJSPfile.jsp

Comment: Это верно не только для томкат. Вероятно в документацию оракла закралась ошибка.